# Wanting buttons at bottom of content page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am doing one of the app designs on up laps and I am using the following for the home page which is a Sign In / Create Count

I am using an app shell and below is my content page however I need the buttons to appear at the bottom of the image however at the present its appearing at the top,

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Image Source="TeslaBackground.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="End">
       <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="btnSignIn"   Text="Sign in" />
      <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="btnCreateAccount" Text="Create Account" />
 </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

They should appear just above the tab bar ?

Comment: if you're using an AbsoluteLayout, you need to specify where you want your controls placed, otherwise they default to the top left.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with stacklayout, Example:

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
         <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="btnSignIn"   Text="Sign in" />
         <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="btnCreateAccount" Text="Create Account" />
  </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need the buttons to appear at the bottom of the image however at the present its appearing at the top

From shared code , only setting `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` to Image .Also need to `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` to the `StackLayout` inside the root `AbsoluteLayout`.

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Image Source="TeslaBackground.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,1,.5,.1">
       <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="btnSignIn"   Text="Sign in" />
      <telerikInput:RadButton x:Name="btnCreateAccount" Text="Create Account" />
 </StackLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

here my setting is:

```
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".5,1,.5,.1"
```

You can refer to the offical document about **[Specifying Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout#specifying-values)** to change each value of it to fit your want.

Views within an AbsoluteLayout are positioned using four values:

- X – the x (horizontal) position of the view's anchor
- Y – the y (vertical) position of the view's anchor
- Width – the width of the view
- Height – the height of the view

Each of those values can be set as a proportional value or an absolute value.

Values are specified as a combination of bounds and a flag. `LayoutBounds` is a [Rectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.rectangle?view=xamarin-forms) consisting of four values: `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`.